# Building tensorflow and jupyter from dockerfiles. Browser refuses to connect

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to build the tensorflow docker images using the instructions here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles

I can build the images fine, but when I try to run the container using this command:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v $(pwd):/my-devel -it tf
```

I get the generic browser error:
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect

What am I missing to connect to the Jupyter notebook for this image?
The terminal output when running the container is:

```
[I 19:07:10.171 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/paths.py:68: UserWarning: IPython parent '/' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
" using a temp directory.".format(parent))
[I 19:07:10.336 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /notebooks
[I 19:07:10.336 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 19:07:10.336 NotebookApp] http://(548975befb14 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=78e9888220f4d92b6b4926540c3e1df6ee0d29079b3fd197
[I 19:07:10.336 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Comment: Silly question, but what exactly did you open up in the browser address bar? From the terminal output, looks like the notebook is on port `8888`, so you would have to visit the URL: `127.0.0.1:8888`, not just `127.0.0.1`

Comment: fair question. I did add the port to the url though :-)

Comment: Ah, okay :-) So with docker you typically have to also map the port with `-p`, like their example for using with Jupyter: `# Images with Jupyter run on port 8888, and needs a volume for notebooks
$ docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/notebooks -it tf`. It looks like the command you used was a line above, missing the `-p` flag? Otherwise the port is not visible to your host machine.

Comment: ok thanks I'll give this a try

Comment: Did setting the port work?